Android: How to set Max Width to match parent's width with layout_width="wrap_content"?
The width of the TextView below needs to match it's content width (in a ConstraintLayout), however when the content includes a long text, it currently extends horizontally beyond the width of the parent - as a single line. How do I make it wrap to multiple lines, instead?
Will setting android:maxWidth work? How do I set it to the parent's width (not a constant)?
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/hold_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="could be a short or a long label" />


I've tested this, and it works as expected! The text wraps to a new line when it gets too long to fit in one line.

Can you provide more code on how the parent element you are setting up is?

Thanks for the quick response. It was an issue with the parent's layout. See my commend below.

Use this line of code

app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"


Thanks for the quick response.
Apparently, changing the parent's layout-width to match parent
(android:layout_width="match_parent" instead of wrap_content) - solved the issue.

@GK100 I misunderstood, I thought you meant to use the content width when the content is smaller than the parent width, and the parent width when it is larger than the parent width.
In your case, match_parent is the easiest to use

If you want your textview to take full screen width you can simply use
 android:layout_width="match_parent"

instead of
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"

But if you want to set the width according to the constraints using  android:layout_width="0dp". and then manage the maxWidth of the textView then you can do is add this attribute.
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintWidth_max="200dp"

NOTE : The 0dp will only work with constraint layout with correct contraints set.
